# PHP static::DerivedClassName

Tags: php, reflection, php-5.3

Is there any way to get the Derived Class Name from static Keyword ?
What I actually want to do is.

Make a Reflection of the Derived Class
Check Wheather it implements the Specified Class or not

I've a static method the Base Class say its named `Base::check()`
I want `Base::check()` will check for the existence of the Interface Implementation.
the check() method knows the name of the interface.so I don't need to tell it from outer world.

But if there is no way to get DerivedClassName from static Keyword I need to pass the Class Name to the method from the outer world. Which is not a good Coding Principle.

Another Alternative I can do is. I can make an `::instance()` static method that returns the `this` and I can do a get_class from its return. But this also tweeks my Application Principle.

So is the first method really possible ? or I need to go for some alternative of this kind ?
Or Do you have any other kind of Alternatives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand what you are trying to do, especially what you mean by "*get the Derived Class Name from static Keyword*". Check out the following functions to see if they do what you want to do:

- [`class_implements`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php) —  Return the interfaces which are implemented by the given class
- [`class_parents`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.class-parents.php) —  Return the parent classes of the given class
- [`is_a`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) — Checks if the object is of this class or has this class as one of its parents
- [`is_subclass_of`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php) — Checks if the object has this class as one of its parents
- [`instanceof` Type Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php)

If you are refering to [Late Static binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), have a look at

- [`get_called_class`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) — the "Late Static Binding" class name

---

I suppose you are trying to do something like this:

```
class Base
{
    public static function check()
    {
        return in_array('IFoo', class_implements(get_called_class(), FALSE));
        // or
        $instanceClassName = get_called_class();
        return new $instanceClassName instanceof IFoo;
        // or
        $reflector = new ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
        return $reflector->implementsInterface('IFoo');           
    }
}
interface IFoo {};
class Foo extends Base implements IFoo {}

var_dump( Foo::check() );
```

Comment: You have the `static` keyword with you and you are asked to get the name of the class. Thats the thing.

Comment: Ya Thanks. I was missing that get_called_class() works in static.